# couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, std

I'm trying to make a logger lib by using source_location::current() as a default parameter when call assign function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct log_helper { 
    log_helper(const T& o, std::source_location sl = std::source_location::current()) 
        : value(o), sl(sl) {}
    T value;
    std::source_location sl;
};

struct ratio_t {
    operator double() const {
        return ratio;
    }

    // ratio_t(double ratio = 0) : ratio(ratio) {
    //     printf("%p: construct\n", this);
    // }

    template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
    ratio_t& operator=(const log_helper<std::type_identity_t<T>>& o) {
        ratio = o.value;
        
        line = o.sl.line();
        func = o.sl.file_name();
        printf("file: %s line: %d\n", func.c_str(), line);

        return *this;
    }

    void clear() {
        ratio = 0.0f;
        line = 0;
        func.clear();
    }

    double get_ratio() const {
        return ratio;
    }

    uint32_t get_line() const {
        return line;
    }

    std::string get_func() const {
        return func;
    }
private:
    double ratio{0.0f};
    uint32_t line{0};

    std::string func;
};

int main() {
    ratio_t a;
    // a.operator=<double>(log_helper(1.0));
    // a.operator=<double>(1.0); // it works
    a = 1.0; // <- problem here
}
```

But I get this error:

```cpp
b.cpp: In function 'int main()':
b.cpp:61:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'ratio_t' and 'double')
   61 |     a = 1.0;
      |         ^~~
b.cpp:23:14: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class> ratio_t& ratio_t::operator=(const log_helper<typename std::type_identity<_Tp>::type>&)'
   23 |     ratio_t& operator=(const log_helper<std::type_identity_t<T>>& o) {
      |              ^~~~~~~~
b.cpp:23:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
b.cpp:61:9: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   61 |     a = 1.0;
      |         ^~~
b.cpp:13:8: note: candidate: 'ratio_t& ratio_t::operator=(const ratio_t&)'
   13 | struct ratio_t {
      |        ^~~~~~~
b.cpp:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double' to 'const ratio_t&'
b.cpp:13:8: note: candidate: 'ratio_t& ratio_t::operator=(ratio_t&&)'
b.cpp:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double' to 'ratio_t&&'
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9hbzejaWW

If I explicitly implement the assign, the progmma will work. However this is not what I expected. I don't realize there could be any other deduction. so how can I fix it?

```cpp
    a.operator=<double>(log_helper(1.0));
    a.operator=<double>(1.0);
```

Comment: Template deduction type can happen only directly it must be perfect match. If you need conversions then this disables deduction. And you need conversion from `double` to `log_helper<double>`.

Comment: @MarekR Yeah, I get that it will work if I explicit convert `double`  to `log_helper<double>`. But why compiler do an implicit conversation here? The construct of `log_helper` isn't declared with `explicit`.

Comment: @xujh implicit conversion is the default. `explicit` modifies it to be explicit

Comment: @Caleth I mean that the construct function of `log_helper` is implicit. So I think the compiler will help implicit convert `double` to `log_helper<double>` when I call `ratio_t.operator=`

Comment: @xujh but only if it knows to use `log_helper<double>`, which it can't from just a double. Template deduction is done before conversions

Comment: @Caleth Hhhh. So If there is any method that helps compiler to know to use `log_helper<double>` (The only way I can think of is to drop the template）? All my claim is just to execute `a=1.0;` directly

Comment: @xujh yes, if you drop the template, then `log_helper<double>` is implicitly convertible from `double`, and you can have your assignment

Answer (score 1):

`T` is in a non-deduced context here, so you always have to specify it. If you remove `std::type_identity_t` from the declaration, you can have `T` be deduced from `log_helper(1.0)`, but still not `1.0`.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75cda9e2272688bb)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, isn't that `std::type_identity_t` is used for this implicit conversions? Frankly, I'm not very good at its usage

Comment: @xujh no, `std::type_identity_t` is used to introduce a non-deduced context

Comment: I'm a little confused by your statement. I'm actually trying to use `std::type_identity_t` to avoid the explicit conversion. I cannot understand why it don't work here.

Comment: @xujh it is not about covertion, but about template deduction. Since `std::type_identity_t` introduces depended type (underneath it is: `typename std::type_identity::type`) it prevents compiler from deducing type and forces developer to explicitly specify that type.

Comment: Dropping use of `std::type_identity_t` makes your code a bit better https://godbolt.org/z/E9jThWrKh , but I do not think it is possible to achieve line number on this kind of assignment.

Comment: @MarekR Actually, I'd like to substitude `ratio_t ratio` for `double ratio` in my project. So, it may lead to a lot of changes that I dont want